# PHP: Field names of an odbc_exec query are empty

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc, sql-server-2016

I'm using odbc_exec to execute a stored procedure in my local DB (SQL server 2016), and expect to return records as results. However, the field names of results (odbc_field_name) are all empty.

The value of the records are correct. And when I ran the query on SSMS, the results looks well. Followings are my sample code.

PHP:

```
$connection = odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=$myServer;Database=$myDB;", $myUser, $myPass) or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer");
$query = "dbo.[TestSP]";
$result = odbc_exec($connection,$query) or die(odbc_error($connection));
$counter = 0;
while($counter < odbc_num_fields($result))
{
    $counter = $counter + 1;
    $test_str.= odbc_field_name($result,$counter)."\n";
}
$file = 'log.txt';
$current = file_get_contents($file);
$current .= $test_str;
file_put_contents($file, $current);
```

SQL:

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[TestSP] AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT '1' as first_column, '2' as second_column
END
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated

**Updated**

It works after upgrading PHP from 5.4 to 7.0. Still not sure why it happens... I'll compare php config later and will update it if I identify anything. Thanks all your help

Comment: I think pasting the specific sql might help

Comment: @yakobom Thanks for the suggestion. Just added

Comment: It works after upgrading PHP from 5.4 to 7.0. I'm still not sure why it happens. Hope I'll have time to track the details later.
Thanks all your help

Answer (score 0):

That looks like it *should* work. But that ODBC code is pretty old at this point, and probably flaky. If you can't switch to PDO, maybe try retrieving an associative array? (It's possible that the driver just doesn't get that info though.)

```
$connection = odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=$myServer;Database=$myDB;", $myUser, $myPass) or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer");
$query = "dbo.[TestSP]";
$result = odbc_exec($connection, $query) or die(odbc_error($connection));
$row = odbc_fetch_array($result);
odbc_free_result($result);

foreach ($row as $k=>$v)
{
    $test_str.= "$k\n";
}
$file = 'log.txt';
file_put_contents($file, $test_str, FILE_APPEND);
```

Note also that `file_put_contents` can append!